# How can I correctly handle a Guzzle ClientException? Can I put my call into something like a Java try catch block in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, exception, guzzle

I am an absolute beginner in PHP (I came from Java) and I have the following problem related to how to handle an exception.

I am using Guzzle to perform a call to a REST web service, something like this:

```
    $client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client

    $response = $client->get('http://localhost:8080/Extranet/login',
        [
            'auth' => [
                $credentials['email'],
                $credentials['password']
            ]
        ]);

    $dettagliLogin = json_decode($response->getBody());
```

If in the response my web service returns an existing user information I have no problem.

If the user doesn't exist my web service return something like this:

```
[2017-01-30 11:24:44] local.INFO: INSERTED USER CREDENTIAL: pippo@google.com dddd  
[2017-01-30 11:24:44] local.ERROR: exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException' with message 'Client error: `GET http://localhost:8080/Extranet/login` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
{"timestamp":1485775484609,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Bad credentials","path":"/Extranet/login"}
```

So it seems to me that in this case the client throws a **ClientException**.

My doubt is: can I put this **$client->get(...)** into something like a Java **try catch** block so if a **ClientException** is catched I can handle it creating a custom response?

Comment: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#exceptions and http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#http-errors

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use the similar to **try catch block**.

You could use the Guzzle Exception like it is stated over here:

> http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#exceptions
>   http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#http-errors

I have plucked the code from the above docs:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

try {
    $client->request('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/Extranet/login');
} catch (RequestException $e) {
    echo Psr7\str($e->getRequest());
    if ($e->hasResponse()) {
        echo Psr7\str($e->getResponse());
    }
}
```

You could modify and handle the exception for whatever purpose you want.